# Click button to get value from nearby input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that comes after an input in the HTML, and I want to use that button to retrieve the value from that input and perform an action. The problem I'm facing is that my jQuery isn't finding that value.

The HTML:

```
<div>
    <input class="an-input" type="text"></input>
    <button class="ui-state-default inputButton an-button">GO</button>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
$('.an-button').click(function() {
    var inputValue = $('.an-button').prev('.an-input').find('input').val();
    window.open('http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/JobsQueryByNumberServlet?passjobnumber='+inputValue+'&passdocnumber=&go10=+GO+&requestid=0');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Travel up the DOM with `closest`:

```
 var inputValue = $('.an-button').closest('div').find('input').val();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x85e7o2q/)

Answer (score 2):

Try removing `.find('input')` , as `.prev(".an-input")` should return  `input` element . Also note, `<input />` tag is self-closing

```js
$(".an-button").click(function() {
    var inputValue = $(this).prev(".an-input").val();
    console.log(inputValue)
    //window.open('http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/JobsQueryByNumberServlet?passjobnumber='+inputValue+'&passdocnumber=&go10=+GO+&requestid=0');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>
    <input class="an-input" type="text" />
    <button class="ui-state-default inputButton an-button">GO</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button.an-button').click(function() {
    var inputValue = $('.an-input:text').val();
  ... rest of code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To target a sibling, it must be of similar type.

Try this instead:

```
$('.an-button').click(function() {
    var inputValue = $('.an-button').parent().find('.an-input').val();
    window.open('http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/JobsQueryByNumberServlet?passjobnumber='+inputValue+'&passdocnumber=&go10=+GO+&requestid=0');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The input element has not end tag

more information [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element)

the correct is <input />

Comment: You should add the core concepts and content from the link as links can become obsolete of time.