# Best way to return the value of an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given this HTML:

```
<div>
    <input class="class_one" type="text" />
    <button class="class_two">GO</button>
</div>
```

If I want to get the value of the input, why should I use

```
$('.class_two').click(fucntion() {
    var inputValue = $(this).closest('div').find('input').val();
});
```

Rather than the simpler

```
$('.class_two').click(fucntion() {
    var inputValue = $('.class_one').val();
});
```

Comment: Well, you shouldn't use the long way, and as much as possible, avoid using selectors that rely on the relationship between elements. You'll have more versatile code.

Comment: Why are you asking us? It seems like something you can answer yourself.

Comment: It's like asking why should I do `12+1*3-2/2-12` instead of `1+1`.

Comment: I am asking my question based on answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906118/click-button-to-get-value-from-nearby-input

Comment: You forgot the `dot` in the class name, should be `$('.class_one')`

Comment: Because you can have more than one element with that class and need to reference the one that is close to it.... It is like me yelling Peter into a room. I might get one guy or I might get 5 that answer me. If there are more than one, you need to narrow it done to an area of the room.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/dkmgtyt6/)***

Usually when dealing with class names, they refer to a class of elements - as in a set of them. Relying on the ability to reference that entire set and properly target the exact element that you are looking for is problematic. Stick to querying locally, it is much more efficient performance wise as well.

As for your exact example.. use siblings. And remember, `.className` for `class="className"`.

```
$('.class_two').click(fucntion() {
    var inputValue = $(this).siblings('.class_one').val();
});
```